# Tabs on partial layout under static contents in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I want to make a layout as shown in the image below. On the top, there are common widgets required to be there always and similarly at the bottom. The tabs I want only in the middle for the two and should control only the portion which is under those tabs. Common widgets are independent of the tabs.

[image]

I tried many ways to achieve this. I am able to get tabs on top or bottom of the display but not at the middle. The tabs are not showing up at all but the objects under the tab are showing overlapping each other in the same display.

Please suggest how to make this layout.

Comment: Please post your layout file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewPager Indicator` Library.

Download from https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

And make ur layout something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/another_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/main_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can put tab any where u want.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a custom layout in the ActionBar

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.myactionbar);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

In your layout (myactionbar) you put the text, the image and manually draw the tabs below them.
It involves some work, since those are not "real" tabs. you can create real tabs and manually call `onTabSelected()`, `onTabUnselected()` by setting the `onClick()` listener to the textViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="YOUR TEXT" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator_holo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TAB1" />

        <View style="@style/SeparatorVertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator_holo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TAB2" />

        <View style="@style/SeparatorVertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator_holo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TAB3" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks ilomambo for the suggestion. Making custom layout is cumbersome. I believe, there should be some way to achieve this - perhaps using fragments. I am looking for some expert advice before exploring custom layout.